# How did they get the solution for this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

if v1 and v2 are basis vectors of B (which are given), then the matrix would be
|0 0|
|1 0|
.

Comment: Can you argue what should happen to these two basis vectors when they are projected onto this line?

Comment: Why do you believe that your answer is correct? How did you arrive at it?